# C programming calling a function...passing (float*)X to a function

Tags: c, function, prototype

I have the following code shown below

To call the function the code looks similar to the following:

```
#define N 2
static float m1[N][N] = {{1.0, -0.02}, {0.0, 1.0}};
static float m2[N][1] = {{1.5f}, {1.5f}};
static float result[N][1];

int main(void)
{
    matrix_multiply((float*) m1, (float*) m2, N, N, 1, (float*) result);
}

void matrix_multiply(float* input_matrix1, float* input_matrix2, int m, int p, int n, float* output_matrix)
{
    // Matrix Multiplication Routine
    // input_matrix1= input matrix (m x p)
    // input_matrix2 = input matrix (p x n)
    // m = number of rows in input_matrix1
    // p = number of columns in input_matrix1 which should equal the number of rows in input_matrix2
    // n = number of columns in input_matrix2
    // output_matrix = output matrix = input_matrix1*input_matrix2 (m x n)
    //.....Code that does matrix multiplication
}
```

I haven't come across the `(float*)` being used when calling a function. Can someone describe it in detail.

Comment: C multidimensional arrays are laid out in a contiguous block (it's really a linear array, just with some arithmetic conveniences)

Comment: The casts in the `main()` are ugly and unnecessary.  The call can be written accurately, without casts, in various ways.  I'd probably use: `matrix_multiply(&m1[0][0], &m2[0][0], n, n, 1, &result[0][0]);`  If you've got C99, you can revise the function prototype to: `void matrix_multiply(int m, int p, int n, float matrix1[m][p], float matrix2[p][n], float result[m][n])` and the call becomes `matrix_multiply(n, n, 1, m1, m2, result);` which is simpler still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation `(float *)X` is a cast.  The cast is necessary if the matrix multiply function is declared (or defined) before it is used, as it should be, because the types being passed to the function are not `float *` as the function expects but `float (*)[2]` (which is a pointer to an array).  The casts tell the compiler 'we know more about this C than you do', even though that is a very debatable proposition.

Here is a mildly modified version of the code in the question:

```
#define N 2
static float m1[N][N] = {{1.0, -0.02}, {0.0, 1.0}};
static float m2[N][1] = {{1.5f}, {1.5f}};
static float result[1][N];

void matrix_multiply(float *input_matrix1, float *input_matrix2, int m, int p, int n, float *output_matrix);

int main(void)
{
    matrix_multiply( m1,  m2, N, N, 1,  result);

    matrix_multiply(&m1[0][0], &m2[0][0], N, N, 1, &result[0][0]);

    matrix_multiply((float*) m1, (float*) m2, N, N, 1, (float*) result);
}

void matrix_multiply(float *input_matrix1, float *input_matrix2, int m, int p, int n, float *output_matrix)
{
    // Matrix Multiplication Routine
    // input_matrix1 = input matrix (m x p)
    // input_matrix2 = input matrix (p x n)
    // m = number of rows in input_matrix1
    // p = number of columns in input_matrix1 and the number of rows in input_matrix2
    // n = number of columns in input_matrix2
    // output_matrix = output matrix = input_matrix1*input_matrix2 (m x n)
    //.....Code that does matrix multiplication
}
```

When compiled with GCC 4.7.1 on Mac OS X 10.8.4, the output is:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -c matmul89.c
matmul89.c: In function ‘main’:
matmul89.c:10:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘matrix_multiply’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
matmul89.c:6:6: note: expected ‘float *’ but argument is of type ‘float (*)[2]’
matmul89.c:10:5: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘matrix_multiply’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
matmul89.c:6:6: note: expected ‘float *’ but argument is of type ‘float (*)[1]’
matmul89.c:10:5: warning: passing argument 6 of ‘matrix_multiply’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
matmul89.c:6:6: note: expected ‘float *’ but argument is of type ‘float (*)[2]’
matmul89.c: In function ‘matrix_multiply’:
matmul89.c:17:29: warning: unused parameter ‘input_matrix1’ [-Wunused-parameter]
matmul89.c:17:51: warning: unused parameter ‘input_matrix2’ [-Wunused-parameter]
matmul89.c:17:70: warning: unused parameter ‘m’ [-Wunused-parameter]
matmul89.c:17:77: warning: unused parameter ‘p’ [-Wunused-parameter]
matmul89.c:17:84: warning: unused parameter ‘n’ [-Wunused-parameter]
matmul89.c:17:94: warning: unused parameter ‘output_matrix’ [-Wunused-parameter]
$
```

The unused parameter warnings are reasonable; the function is still a dummy with no code.  Line 10 is the call to `matrix_multiply()` without the casts.  As you can see, GCC diagnoses that the types of the matrix arguments are not `float *` but are pointers arrays.  The second call is the way I'd write it, avoiding any need for casts.  The third call bludgeons the compiler into accepting the code with the casts, and it will in fact work correctly, but there is really no need to do the bludgeoning.

#### Working C99 code

If you've got C99 available, you can make use of VLAs — variable length arrays — to write the code neatly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 2
static float m1[N][N] = {{1.0, -0.02}, {0.0, 1.0}};
static float m2[N][1] = {{1.5f}, {1.5f}};
static float result[1][N];

void matrix_multiply(int m, int p, int n, float matrix1[m][p], float matrix2[p][n], float output[m][n]);
void matrix_print(const char *tag, int m, int n, float matrix[m][n]);

int main(void)
{
    matrix_multiply(N, N, 1, m1, m2, result);
    matrix_print("m1", N, N, m1);
    matrix_print("m2", N, 1, m2);
    matrix_print("m3", 1, N, result);
}

void matrix_multiply(int m, int p, int n, float matrix1[m][p], float matrix2[p][n], float output[m][n])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            output[i][j] = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < p; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                output[i][k] += matrix1[i][j] * matrix2[j][k];
}

void matrix_print(const char *tag, int m, int n, float matrix[m][n])
{
    printf("%s (%d x %d):\n", tag, m, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        char *pad = "[";
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%s%6.3f", pad, matrix[i][j]);
            pad = ", ";
        }
        printf("%s", " ]\n");
    }
}
```

This compiles without warnings and produces the plausible-looking output:

```
m1 (2 x 2):
[ 1.000, -0.020 ]
[ 0.000,  1.000 ]
m2 (2 x 1):
[ 1.500 ]
[ 1.500 ]
m3 (1 x 2):
[ 1.470,  1.500 ]
```

Writing the code to simulate the address arithmetic using C89 is fiddly — far from impossible, but fiddly.

---

#### Working C89 code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 2
static float m1[N][N] = {{1.0, -0.02}, {0.0, 1.0}};
static float m2[N][1] = {{1.5f}, {1.5f}};
static float result[1][N];

void matrix_multiply(float *matrix1, float *matrix2, int m, int p, int n, float *output);
void matrix_print(const char *tag, int m, int n, float *matrix);

int main(void)
{
    matrix_multiply(&m1[0][0], &m2[0][0], N, N, 1, &result[0][0]);
    matrix_print("m1", N, N, &m1[0][0]);
    matrix_print("m2", N, 1, &m2[0][0]);
    matrix_print("m3", 1, N, &result[0][0]);
    return 0;
}

/*
** Matrix Multiplication Routine
** matrix1 = input matrix (m x p)
** matrix2 = input matrix (p x n)
** m = number of rows in matrix1
** p = number of columns in matrix1 and number of rows in matrix2
** n = number of columns in matrix2
** output = output matrix = matrix1 * matrix2 (m x n)
*/
void matrix_multiply(float *matrix1, float *matrix2, int m, int p, int n, float *output)
{
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            output[i*n+j] = 0.0;

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < p; j++)
            for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
                output[i*n+k] += matrix1[i*p+j] * matrix2[j*n+k];
}

void matrix_print(const char *tag, int m, int n, float *matrix)
{
    int i, j;

    printf("%s (%d x %d):\n", tag, m, n);
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        char *pad = "[";
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%s%6.3f", pad, matrix[i*n+j]);
            pad = ", ";
        }
        printf("%s", " ]\n");
    }
}
```

The output for the C89 and C99 code is the same.

Comment: This helped clarify things. To those reading C89 is indeed fiddly and will not allow you to use dual arrays.E.G in function matrix_multiply you the line output[i][k]+=..... will spit out an error in function matrix multiply.