# C Programming: doing matrix multiplication of two contiguous, row-major arrays

Tags: c, math, matrix

I'm trying to write a function that does naive matrix multiplication of two contiguous, row-major arrays.  But when I attempt to print each value at the end I get garbage.  I'm guessing it's because I've mixed up the proper iterations and scaling needed to jump rows/columns.  Does anyone have any advice?

Full code necessary is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void dmatmul(double *a, double *b, double *c, int astride, int bstride, int cdim_0, int cdim_1) {
    int i, j, p;

    for (i = 0; i < cdim_0; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cdim_1; j++) {
            c[i * cdim_1 + j] = 0.0;
            for (p = 0; p < (astride); p++) {
                c[i * cdim_1 + j] += a[i * (astride) + p] * b[p * (bstride) + j];
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    double *x, *y, *z;
    int xdim_0, xdim_1, ydim_0, ydim_1, zdim_0, zdim_1, i, j;

    xdim_0 = 2;
    xdim_1 = 4;
    ydim_0 = 4;
    ydim_1 = 2;
    zdim_0 = 2;
    zdim_1 = 2;

    x = (double *) malloc (xdim_0 * xdim_1 * sizeof(double));
    y = (double *) malloc (ydim_0 * ydim_1 * sizeof(double));
    z = (double *) malloc (zdim_0 * zdim_1 * sizeof(double));

    for (i = 0; i < xdim_0 * xdim_1; i++) {
        x[i] = i + 1;
        y[i] = 2 * (i + 1);
    }

    dmatmul(x, y, z, xdim_1, ydim_1, zdim_0, zdim_1);
    printf("\nMatrix product of X and Y dimensions: (%d, %d)\n", zdim_0, zdim_1);
    printf("Matrix product of X and Y values:");
    for (i = 0; i < zdim_0; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j < zdim_1; i++) {
            printf("\t%f", z[i * zdim_1 + j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Create yourself a function to print a matrix — and call it to print the two matrices that are being multiplied to ensure that they contain what you expect.  And use it to print the result too.

Comment: Your initialization loop is fragile; in general, the x and y matrices need not have the same size.  You can have M1 of size PxQ and M2 of size QxR, and it is not required that P and R are equal, and therefore PxQ is not equal to QxR in general.

Comment: Take a look at [C programming calling a function...passing (float*)X to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17192011/c15168) — which isn't a very good title.  My answer there has C99 code using the VLA notation, and C89 code doing indexing into 1D arrays, like you're trying to do.

Comment: Your inner loop for printing is wrong.  You have: `for (j = 0; j < zdim_1; i++) { … }` but you need to increment `j`, not `i` — `for (j = 0; j < zdim_1; j++) { … }`

Comment: Ah, that’s embarrassing!  I was getting an endless stream of bunk at the print but wasn’t sure if it was an issue with going out of array bounds in the matmul.  Thanks for all the advice!  I was printing the matrices prior because I also used a transpose function (left out here) and that seemed to be fine, but there I was printing in one loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary problem is a typo in the inner `for` loop doing the printing.  You have:

```
for (j = 0; j < zdim_1; i++)
```

but you ned to increment `j`, not `i`:

```
for (j = 0; j < zdim_1; j++)
```

Here's my code, which has an independent matrix printing function appropriate for the arrays you're using:

```
/* SO 7516-7451 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void dmatmul(double *a, double *b, double *c, int astride, int bstride, int cdim_0, int cdim_1)
{
    int i, j, p;

    for (i = 0; i < cdim_0; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < cdim_1; j++)
        {
            c[i * cdim_1 + j] = 0.0;
            for (p = 0; p < (astride); p++)
            {
                c[i * cdim_1 + j] += a[i * (astride) + p] * b[p * (bstride) + j];
            }
        }
    }
}

static void mat_print(const char *tag, int rows, int cols, double *matrix)
{
    printf("%s (%dx%d):\n", tag, rows, cols);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            printf("%4.0f", matrix[i * cols + j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int xdim_0 = 2;
    int xdim_1 = 4;
    int ydim_0 = 4;
    int ydim_1 = 2;
    int zdim_0 = 2;
    int zdim_1 = 2;
    double *x = (double *)malloc(xdim_0 * xdim_1 * sizeof(double));
    double *y = (double *)malloc(ydim_0 * ydim_1 * sizeof(double));
    double *z = (double *)malloc(zdim_0 * zdim_1 * sizeof(double));

    for (int i = 0; i < xdim_0 * xdim_1; i++)
    {
        x[i] = i + 1;
        y[i] = 2 * (i + 1);
    }

    mat_print("X", xdim_0, xdim_1, x);
    mat_print("Y", ydim_0, ydim_1, y);

    dmatmul(x, y, z, xdim_1, ydim_1, zdim_0, zdim_1);

    mat_print("Z", zdim_0, zdim_1, z);

    printf("\nMatrix product of X and Y dimensions: (%d, %d)\n", zdim_0, zdim_1);
    printf("Matrix product of X and Y values:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < zdim_0; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < zdim_1; j++)
            printf("\t%f", z[i * zdim_1 + j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've also initialized the variables as I declared them.  The code should, but does not, check that the memory was allocated.

When I ran this code without your printing, I got the correct result, so then I took a good look at that and saw the problem.

```
X (2x4):
   1   2   3   4
   5   6   7   8
Y (4x2):
   2   4
   6   8
  10  12
  14  16
Z (2x2):
 100 120
 228 280

Matrix product of X and Y dimensions: (2, 2)
Matrix product of X and Y values:
    100.000000  120.000000
    228.000000  280.000000
```